# implementation of QuickDialogue shows QRootElement undeclared identifier

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using QuickDialogue for my form building. After following all instruction of http://escoz.com/open-source/quickdialog I am getting an error in my viewcontroller that QRootElement object is undeclared one. I tried declaring it in .h file however it still shows the same.

What is the correct way to use the form builder?

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     QRootElement *root = [[QRootElement alloc] init];
     root.title = @"Hello World";
     root.grouped = YES;
     QSection *section = [[QSection alloc] init];
     QLabelElement *label = [[QLabelElement alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" Value:@"world!"];
     [root addSection:section];
     [section addElement:label];
     UINavigationController *navigation = [QuickDialogController controllerWithNavigationForRoot:root];   
     [self presentModalViewController:navigation animated:YES]; 
 }
```

Comment: Did you #import <QuickDialog/QuickDialog.h> to your Prefix.pch file?

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have there is mostly alright (other than the fact that you're presenting the modal view controller from inside the viewdidload, which is really not the right place for it).

Your problem seems to be with the instalation of QD on your project. Make sure you follow [all the steps on the installation](http://escoz.com/open-source/quickdialog), specially the Build Settings tab part.

Comment: where should I put this code so that it would start working...where ever I try to put...it does not recognize the QRootElement..

Comment: did you follow all the steps to set up the project? It explaisn where to put the QuickDialog.h import, which should fix this.

Comment: Yes...I got that right and those errors are gone now however I still cant see the form...where should I put above code....Appdelegate or viewDidLoad...Please let me know...

Comment: That code should go into a viewcontroller, although I'm not sure it would work as is. Take a look at the demo app that comes with QuickDialog, or join the forum here to ask for more info on how to use it: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/quickdialog